# PyJWT not raising an ExpiredSignatureError

Tags: python, authentication, jwt

**I'll come straight to the point:**

1. I create the jwt:

```
jwt.encode({'sub':"abc", "iat":datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc), "exp":datetime.now()+timedelta(seconds=1)}, JWT_KEY, algorithm="HS256")
```

2. I wait

```
time.sleep(3)
```

3. I try to validate the `exp` flag:

```
    try:
        return jwt.decode(token, JWT_KEY, algorithms=["HS256"])
    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        raise Exception("JWT expired")
```

**But it won't raise the desired exception even though the current time is behind the exp timestamp**

Comment: see also [Using a pyJWT expiration time](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73837617)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the creation of the token.

I just forgot to add `tz=timezone.utc` into the `exp` flag like I did with the `iat` flag.

So, the working code:

```
jwt.encode({'sub':"abc", "iat":datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc), "exp":datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc)+timedelta(seconds=1)}, JWT_KEY, algorithm="HS256")
```